# Working faster with variables that have almost the same name

Tags: objective-c, loops, variables, if-statement, nsstring

Really strange question but I just can't find the right way to do this on the internet my self.
I have 3 NSStrings. called: string1, string2 and string3.
They all get value from the same UITextfield but at different times. So the values are different from each other.
What happens now is:

```
-(void)statement {
    if (i==0) {
       string1 = nameField.text;
    } else if (i==1) {
        string2 = nameField.text;
    } else if (i==2) {
        string3 = nameField.text;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to replace the 1,2 and 3 of behind the 'string' with a variable or something so I can say something like:

```
-(void)statement {
    stringX = nameField.text;    
}
```

So that I can change X before the statement is activated?

Hope that it's all clear!

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want to use an [array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_arrays.htm)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a mutable array called, for example, myString

```
NSMutableArray *myString = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

then use something like

```
myString[i] = nameField.text
```

Comment: Thank you man, I actually tried it a couple of times with a normal NSArray and that just wouldn't work. Thank you dude

Answer (score 0):

If those strings are properties on an object, you can use KVO:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string3;
```

Setter:

```
[object setValue:nameField.text forKey:[NSString withFormat:@"string%@", @(i)]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Or create a selector and perform it:

```
// assuming
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string3;

// then
-(void)statement {
    NSString *selName = [NSString withFormat:@"setString%@", @(i)];
    SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(selName);
    [self performSelector:sel withObject:nameField.text afterDelay:0];
}
```